# pass paramter from batch to mysql file

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I try hard to get my batch to pass parameter to mysql file

my batch :

---

```
SET MYSQL_EXE="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe"
SET DB_USER=root
SET DB_PWD=viper007
SET DB=db01

FOR %%c in (D:\Dev_Algo\Grt_pce\datas\*.*) do (
    set "str=%%c"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    call set "str=%%str:\=/%%"
    echo SET @fpath ='!str!' > params.sql
    ENDLOCAL
    type params.sql D:\Dev_Algo\Grt_pce\query0.sql | mysql --user=%DB_USER% --password=%DB_PWD% --database=%DB%    
    )
```

my params.sql file

---

```
SET @fpath ='D:/Dev_Algo/Grt_pce/datas/LBFLO007.csv'
```

My sql file (extract)

---

```
SET @file=@fpath;
LOAD DATA INFILE @file IGNORE INTO TABLE db01.tblpce
    fields terminated by ';'
    ignore 1 lines
```

Result
 - I can connect to mysql NO PROBLEM
 - I can load my file with SQL command from MYSQL Workbench
 - Params file is OK withe single quotes needed for LOAD DATA INFILE
 - I can't set variable @fpath. I got the error message from batch

ERROR 1064(4200) at line 1 : You have an error in your SQL synthax; check the manual......'SET @file=@fpath' at line 2

I read this http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39115 , apparently this functionaly is not implemented. Is this limitation is linked with my error message.

How can I bypass this error, in order to import bulks csv into mysql.

Comment: If your `params.sql` doesn't have a newline at the end, `type` command won't add it, so mysql will see `SET @fpath ='.......'SET @file=@fpath;`

Comment: I just add echo. >> params.sql . I got the same error .'SET @file=@fpath' at line 3

Comment: Actually even without the new echo. >>params.sql . This file has 2 line (1 is blank)

Comment: it seems tha t > or >> add return cariage and it seems that in order to work I must not have a new line !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually replace `@file` with the actual path (using [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044), for example), save the result in another .sql file, use it with mysql.

```
set "str=%%c"
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
call set "str=%%str:\=/%%"
call jrepl "@file" "'!str!'" <D:\Dev_Algo\Grt_pce\query0.sql >query.sql
ENDLOCAL
type query.sql | mysql --user=%DB_USER% --password=%DB_PWD% --database=%DB%
```

And remove `SET @file=@fpath;` line from your sql file.